# Maven project create option unavailable in categories on netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, maven-3, netbeans-7

I want to create a maven project on netbeans 7.3.1 which comes bundled with maven 3.0.5. Couple of days ago, I created a maven project successfully. But today I dont see maven option the categories of new project window only. Any clues?

Comment: that would mean that the maven related modules are missing or are not enabled? try checking your IDE log file to see if there are any maven modules on startup. Also can you "open" a maven project?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem when I've upgraded from 7.3 to 7.4. In 7.3 I had the "Groovy and Grails" module but I haven't installed it in 7.4, although I clicked to import settings from 7.3.
My solution was to **remove the folder under C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\config\Templates** (in particular there was a folder named C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\config\Templates\Project\Groovy\Maven2 )